# The difference between ‘It was at one o’clock’ and ‘It was one o’clock’?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The difference between:

> 1. It was **at** one o’clock

and

> 2. It was one o’clock’

I saw these two sentence in one book.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 tells that **something** ("it") **happened** when it was 1 o'clock.

Sentence 2 tells that the **time** of day **was** 1 o'clock (not sure if in the morning or in the afternoon).